# How to show 3 button in the same line on a table, who have 3 different form?

Tags: html, css

I've some problems about a table who have a  with 3 buttons, the problems is that:
This buttons are on 3 different forms, and they are showed as column, but I want it to be showed in line, any suggestions? this is my actual code:

```html
<div class="text-center">
    <!-- PRIMO BOTTONE -->
    <s:form action="esportaCommesseByRichiesta" cssClass="form-same-row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Esporta Richiesta">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </s:form>
    <!-- PRIMO BOTTONE -->


    <!-- SECONDO BOTTONE -->
    <s:form action="editCommesseGl" cssClass="form-same-row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" title="Modifica Richiesta">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </s:form>
    <!-- SECONDO BOTTONE -->


    <!-- TERZO BOTTONE -->
    <s:form action="#" cssClass="form-same-row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cancella Richiesta">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </s:form>
    <!-- TERZO BOTTONE -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create your environment in a codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: actually i cant, becouse if i do, the row is showed properly xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS

```
form {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: yeah, that should do the job!

Comment: It does, than you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have clear idea of your code but Try this code it may helpful....

```
.form-same-row
{
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
}
```